# Woocommerce - Multiple variations with 1 add to cart button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am wondering if there is a possibility for a single "add to cart" button that can be used for multiple product variations at once? I need to simplify my product page, and any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for that....

http://www.woothemes.com/products/bulk-variation-forms/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.